# UIAutomation c# textbox disappears with mouse click or losing focus

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

iam using UIAutomation in  visual c # express  2010 
i am trying to input so text boxes automatically in UI applicton i have succsuffully selected the window i need to input data in but  what happens afer data is entered if i swiched windows or changed the focused filed  the text suddenly disappears here is the UIspy log for the filed i work on

```
AutomationElement
General Accessibility
AccessKey:  ""
AcceleratorKey: ""
IsKeyboardFocusable:    "True"
LabeledBy:  "(null)"
HelpText:   ""

State
IsEnabled:  "True"
HasKeyboardFocus:   "False"

Identification
ClassName:  "Edit"
ControlType:    "ControlType.Edit"
Culture:    "(null)"
AutomationId:   "100"
LocalizedControlType:   "edit"
Name:   ""
ProcessId:  "5172 (Winpoint)"
RuntimeId:  "42 267278"
IsPassword: "False"
IsControlElement:   "True"
IsContentElement:   "True"

Visibility
BoundingRectangle:  "(611, 286, 90, 20)"
ClickablePoint: "(null)"
IsOffscreen:    "False"

  ControlPatterns
  Text
  DocumentRange
  Text: ""
  Length:   "0"
  Bounding Rectangles:  ""
  AnimationStyleAttribute:  "(not supported)"
  BackgroundColorAttribute: "16777215"
  BulletStyleAttribute: "(not supported)"
  CapStyleAttribute:    "None"
  CultureAttribute: "(not supported)"
  FontNameAttribute:    "Microsoft Sans Serif"
  FontSizeAttribute:    "8"
  FontWeightAttribute:  "400"
  ForegroundColorAttribute: "0"
  HorizontalTextAlignmentAttribute: "Left"
  IndentationFirstLineAttribute:    "(not supported)"
  IndentationLeadingAttribute:  "(not supported)"
  IndentationTrailingAttribute: "(not supported)"
  IsHiddenAttribute:    "(not supported)"
  IsItalicAttribute:    "False"
  IsReadOnlyAttribute:  "False"
  IsSubscriptAttribute: "(not supported)"
  IsSuperscriptAttribute:   "(not supported)"
  MarginBottomAttribute:    "(not supported)"
  MarginLeadingAttribute:   "(not supported)"
  MarginTopAttribute:   "(not supported)"
  MarginTrailingAttribute:  "(not supported)"
  OutlineStylesAttribute:   "(not supported)"
  OverlineColorAttribute:   "(not supported)"
  OverlineStyleAttribute:   "(not supported)"
  StrikethroughColorAttribute:  "(not supported)"
  StrikethroughStyleAttribute:  "None"
  TabsAttribute:    "(not supported)"
  TextFlowDirectionsAttribute:  "(not supported)"
  UnderlineColorAttribute:  "(not supported)"
  UnderlineStyleAttribute:  "None"

 Value
  Value:    ""
  IsReadOnly:   "False"
```

and here is the code i am using of course iam targting this filed with the automation id of 100

```
                    AutomationElement firstname = GetTextElement(appElement, "100");
                if (firstname != null)
                {
                    LogMessage("OK " + Environment.NewLine);
                    LogMessage("typing in  the first name...");

                    {


                        ValuePattern firstnameval =
                          firstname.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                        firstnameval.SetValue("basem22");
                      //  firstnameval.Text("basem");
                       // var textbox = AutomationElement(scope, id);
                        ValuePattern p = firstname.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                        p.SetValue("value");
```

so when i run this code the "value" is entered on the textbox but if i changed foucs it disappears any ideas i am trying to input that form automatically and save it .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer i used simply in case any one had the same situation , i found if a keyboard key is pressed the text is saved and don't disappear seems like kind of wpf lag or something any ways here is the fixing code ,

```
//add a letter and delete so text stay
                        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("A");
                        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{HOME}{DELETE}");
```